# Rewrite history using navigation service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightningnavigation

I've got a wizard that utilises `isUrlAddressable` and navigation service to switch between pages.

At some page 3 there's a "point of no return" where Lead gets converted and returning to first page causes all sort of weirdness.

My aim is to rewrite history so I can add Opportunity Id and some other params to URL of first page and have different logic for this case.

Is it possible to do with Lightning navigation service?